# Creating stretches from the onset

Tags: r, dataframe

I am facing a little problem.

I have a table that looks like below and I would like to create a new column with "streches" of 1 values until finding the next 2.

Should I create a :
for (rowi in 1:totalnbofrow){} ?
Is there a simpler way?

```
  Filen Nb  Valu    Valu2   Phase
  File1 01  18.71   2.84    
  File1 02  18.68   2.85    
  File1 03  18.65   2.85    1
  File1 04  18.62   2.86    
  File1 05  18.59   2.86    
  File1 06  18.56   2.86    
  File1 07  18.52   2.86    2
  File1 08  18.49   2.86    
  File1 09  18.46   2.86    
  File1 10  18.44   2.86    
  File1 11  18.41   2.85    1
  File1 12  18.38   2.86    
  File2 01  18.36   2.86    
  File2 02  18.34   2.86    1
  File2 03  18.32   2.85    
  File2 04  18.30   2.86    2
  File2 05  18.32   2.85    
  File2 06  18.32   2.85    1
  File2 07  18.30   2.86
```

Expected Output

```
  Filen Nb  Valu    Valu2   Phase
  File1 01  18.71   2.84    
  File1 02  18.68   2.85    
  File1 03  18.65   2.85    1
  File1 04  18.62   2.86    1
  File1 05  18.59   2.86    1
  File1 06  18.56   2.86    1
  File1 07  18.52   2.86    2
  File1 08  18.49   2.86    2
  File1 09  18.46   2.86    2
  File1 10  18.44   2.86    2
  File1 11  18.41   2.85    1
  File1 12  18.38   2.86    1
  File2 01  18.36   2.86    1
  File2 02  18.34   2.86    1
  File2 03  18.32   2.85    1
  File2 04  18.30   2.86    2
  File2 05  18.32   2.85    2
  File2 06  18.32   2.85    1
  File2 07  18.30   2.86    1
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: You're going to have to define what "stretching" a number means

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the number of `1`s between each `2`, or you want to fill in the blank values of `Phase` with `1`s? And should the blank values of `Phase` be coded as missing (`NA`) or something else?

Comment: I was thinking to filled up the blanks between 1 and 2 with the values (1 or 2). Reading the file down, if a 1 is found, the following values will be 1 until a 2 is found... I am trying to define segments of data to further analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
library(zoo)
df$Phase[df$Phase==''] <- NA
df$newCol <- na.locf(df$Phase, na.rm=FALSE)
df$newCol
#[1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1
```

Or if your expected output is similar to how @eipi10 interpreted, another option is

```
 do.call(pmax,c(list(as.numeric(df$Phase), 1), list(na.rm=TRUE)))
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Or

```
 rowSums(cbind((df$Phase==''), as.numeric(df$Phase)), na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[Phase=='', Phase := '1'][]
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Filen = c("File1", "File1", "File1", "File1", 
 "File1", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File1", 
 "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File2", 
 "File2"), Nb = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Valu = c(18.71, 18.68, 18.65, 
 18.62, 18.59, 18.56, 18.52, 18.49, 18.46, 18.44, 18.41, 18.38, 
 18.36, 18.34, 18.32, 18.3, 18.32, 18.32, 18.3), Valu2 = c(2.84, 
 2.85, 2.85, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.85, 2.86, 
 2.86, 2.86, 2.85, 2.86, 2.85, 2.85, 2.86), Phase = c("", "", 
 "1", "", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "2", 
 "", "1", "")), .Names = c("Filen", "Nb", "Valu", "Valu2", "Phase"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I will try this different options and will get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NicolasStifani  Could you show the expected output in your post?  It is a bit unclear from the description.

Comment: Option 1 is working well. Correct me if I am misunderstanding but it uses the na.locf function which replaces the NA with the most recent non NA value. The zoo package is required and specialized in Z series (time series).

Comment: @NicolasStifani Yes, `no.locf` replace with the most recent NA values and zoo packages is required.

Comment: You meant na.locf instead of no.locf

Comment: @NicolasStifani  oops, that was a typo, thanks for correcting me